# What is Ruby's ThreadGroup for?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I was flicking through the Pickaxe, looking for the documentation on `Thread`, and came across `ThreadGroup`.

The documentation describes what it does, but it doesn't explain what it's for.

Is a thread group related to a thread pool, which I [assumed Ruby doesn't have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840751/why-doesnt-ruby-have-a-threadpool-built-in)?

Comment: Hesitant to leave a real answer but looking at the usages on Google codesearch, I think you've hit the nail on the head, it's a threadpool for so-called greenthreads.

Comment: @RussC I think it's only part the implementation of a thread pool. You have to add job data into a `Queue` and have the threads pop items off the queue. I'm basing this on Wikipedia's definition of a thread pool: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern . Also, starting from ruby 1.9, threads are native and not green.

Answer (score 8):

New threads are created in their parent's ThreadGroup. You can use the ThreadGroup to organize the implicit tree structure given by the parent threads spawning other threads, and use the `list` instance method to get all threads which have not terminated yet, i.e. to define methods operating on all threads in the group.

Additionaly, you can use `enclose` to prohibit adding (or removing) threads to this group, if you run untrusted code and want to keep an eye on the threads it spawns.

Comment: Can you describe why you'd want to use it, rather than what it does?

Comment: Think of it as an array specialized for threads. You could organize a set of concurrent tasks, to check if all tasks of this set are finished for example. Except of the `enclose` method, it's just good for keep your threads organized - the Thread class itself provides no information about who created a thread.

Perheaps an example of an experiment I'm working on: I have a lot of agents running concurrently, separated in teams. I could use ThreadGroups to organize the agent-threads by team, to lower the priority of a team, or to check how many agent-threads of a team are still alive.